# Beta privileges will change with next week's launch

Tags: discussion, beta, launch

At long last, the site will launch! All our hard work here is finally paying off. This is quite exciting. But please be aware that this is not without cost. As painful as it may be initially, users will lose privileges; at least for a little while.

Since it requires less rep to, say, edit other people’s posts on a beta site (1000) than on a full site (2000), vote to close (500 and 3000, respectively). The full list of what's required to do what will be posted here on our FAQ, but until then, I assume it'll be in-line with [the other graduated sites](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation).

I'm posting this here so that people aren't surprised by this. Please be aware that local moderator can't do anything about this. The only way to restore lost privileges is to keep asking great questions and writing great answers.

How do we get people here to have higher reputation scores? Keep voting up those good questions and answers, that's how. Edit questions and answers into shape when they need it, so that others will vote them up. And please, **don't forget to vote on questions**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm looking at the numbers on our current FAQ and for graduated sites, and at [our list of high rep users](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all)...

Basically, there are some things users of our site can do today that won't work when we get launched out of beta.

We only have 11 non-moderators over 2000 rep points.  Only 8 users over 3000 points. One non-moderator over 5000. Over 30 with over 1000 points, though.

That means the really big change is that we'll be going from

> ```
> 500   Vote to close, reopen, or migrate any questions
> 1000  Edit other people’s posts, vote to approve or reject suggested edits
> 1500  Vote to approve or reject suggested tag wiki edits
> 2000  Vote to delete closed questions, access to moderation tools
> 3500  Protect questions to prevent answers by new users
> 4000  Vote to delete negatively voted answers and stronger question deletion votes
> ```

To

> ```
> 2000  Edit other people’s posts, vote to approve or reject suggested edits
> 3000  Vote to close, reopen, or migrate any questions
> 5000  Vote to approve or reject suggested tag wiki edits
> 10000 Vote to delete closed questions, access to moderation tools
> 15000 Protect questions to prevent answers by new users          
> 20000 Vote to delete negatively voted answers and stronger question deletion votes
> ```

The biggest change is the voting on closing, reopening or migrating questions, where we're going from over 70 users that can do it to only 11 non-moderators that can.

### My suggestions for handling the upcoming rep changes:

1. For editing other people's posts, this should be easy enough: anybody can propose an edit and some other higher-rep users can approve it.  If you're one of those 11 non-moderator people over 2000 rep points do please pay attention to proposed edits.
2. For tag wiki edits it's the same thing, just fewer users that can approve.
3. For everything else, leave a comment on the post and flag it for moderator attention. We will be happy to close, reopen, migrate, protect or delete questions or anwers that need it, especially if there's comments from multiple users saying that's what needs to happen.
4. [Vote. Vote. Vote.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/) (so that we get more high reputation users and don't have to worry about this)

Comment: flagging is really critical in those early days after the site goes public